# Не без того чтобы не

Tags: грамматика, семантика

Наткнулся у одного автора на рассуждения по поводу пушкинского текста

*И Таня, скрыв свое волненье,

Не без того, чтоб не вздохнуть,

Пускается в обратный путь.*
(Е.О. 7/XX)

Спрашивается, при такой конструкции фразы, вздохнула героиня или нет?!
К сожалению, кроме самой постановки вопроса автор ничем не порадовал, сбиваясь на какую-то пошлятину. Дальше пишу уже от собственного имени.

Первое ощущение, что придирки беспочвенны, знакомы всем со школы текст никаких сомнений в понимании не вызывает. Но если приглядеться... Здесь ведь двойное отрицание. И это не пресловутое НЕ с НИ, это классический пример именно двух НЕ.

Сравним:
*От Москвы до Бреста

Нет такого места,

Где бы не скитались мы в пыли.*
(Симонов).
Убираем два отрицания  - получаем: везде скитались, всюду.

Ну или совсем простое - на модальных глаголах. *"Не хочу (ничего) не делать"* = хочу делать. *"Не могу не есть до вечера"* = должен есть. И тому подобное.

Так что ж там у Пушкина-то получается?!
По такой схеме устранения двойного отрицания смысл если не точно, то очень близко должен бы соответствовать "без того, чтобы (вздохнуть)". "Без вздоха", то есть. "Без" выступает в роли третьего отрицания, поэтому смыл - отсутствие вздоха. Вроде бы...

Неужели Пушкин ошибся в грамматике? Ну если и ошибся, то не он один.

Вот что пишет Сергей Соловьев, цитируя некоего шляхтича Ерлича: *Петр Могила вел себя благочестиво, трезво... но не без того, чтоб не
был он охотником и до славы мира сего.* ("История государства Российского", т. X.

Или у Распутина: 
А ведь в деревне всякие люди водились, кой у кого и зудело... Не без того, чтоб не зудело. 
("Прошание с матерой").

И девять авторитетных примеров из нацкорпуса (От Леси Украинки до Гоголя) на "не без того чтобы" с последующим НЕ (против одного  без НЕ - у Пришвина, не очень ясного по  смыслу), не оставляющих ни малейшего сомнения в "позитивности" всей конструкции.

Дальше я пас. 
Можете объяснить грамматику этой конструкции на логическом уровне? Или как считают еще один автор, совсем не впечатливший меня своей логикой, это фразеологизм такой?!

Answer (score 2):

А.И.Чижик-Полейко в учебном пособии для студентов-филологов "Стилистика русского языка" говорит:

> Имеются постоянные обороты с
>   двойным отрицанием в составе сложного предложения. Все они
>   экспрессивны и в большинстве случаев имеют окраску устной речи, кроме
>   архаических, книжных. Укажем некоторые из них:
>
> а) Оборот с **не без того, чтобы**... и устаревший — **не без того,
>   чтобы не**..., оба в значении утверждения: не без того, чтобы
>   поскучать — поскучали, не без того, чтоб поворчать — поворчали...

Так что, похоже, это ближе к фразеологизму, причём к устаревшему.

Эксплетивные (вставные, излишние) отрицания можно найти в других выражениях русского языка, например; "боюсь, чтобы не увидели" (это обсуждалось ранее на форуме).  Известно также, что эксплетивное отрицание широко распространено во французском литературном языке (не знаю как в других).

Comment: А ссылочки нету на это пособие? Пока вижу только констатацию некоего факта. Но я его и не отрицаю.

Comment: Эх, самому интересно. Пособие это хвалят, но я нигде не нашёл в электронном виде. Если в гугло-книгах задать поиск в кавычках "Оборот с не без того, чтобы", то её у меня выдаёт единственным результатом.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что здесь действительно имеет место устойчивая грамматическая конструкция ***не без того, чтобы не***.

Это такое **симметричное отрицание**, которое в итоге означает утверждение. А вот отсутствие второй частицы НЕ  может затемнять смысл сказанного.

**(1)** И Таня, скрыв свое волненье, не без того, чтоб не вздохнуть, Пускается в обратный путь.

**Не без того, чтоб (без вздоха). Не без вздоха – со вздохом.**

**(2)** Петр Могила вел себя благочестиво, трезво... но не без того, чтоб не был он охотником (не проявлял он охоты) и до славы мира сего.

**Не без того, чтоб (без проявления охоты).  Не без проявления охоты – проявляя охоту.**

**И по поводу устаревшей формы.** Иногда кажется, что варианты заменяют друг друга, но не всегда. В некоторых случаях отсутствие НЕ **затемняет смысл текста** (как во втором примере):

Петр Могила вел себя благочестиво, трезво... **но не без того, чтоб  был он охотником  и до славы мира сего.**

**Да и в пушкинском тексте** вариант без НЕ воспринимается на слух не сразу, не так чётко. Поэтому эта тема мне не кажется завершенной и ясной во всём.

Comment: А мне совершенно неясно. *Он вел себя благочестиво, но не без того, чтобы не отказаться от предложенной рюмочки водки.* По-моему, он не отказывался от рюмочки, а по-вашему выходит, что отказывался.

Comment: Исходный вариант должен быть утвердительным, тогда конструкция сохраняет этот утвердительный смысл: Он вел себя благочестиво, но соглашался выпить предложенную рюмку водки. Он вел себя благочестиво, но НЕ без того, чтобы НЕ согласиться выпить рюмку водки.